# How to serialize struct with member datatype unsigned __int128 (using gcc)

Tags: c++, serialization, cereal

I have been using the `cereal` c++ [library](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/index.html) to (de)serialize several structs/classes in my codebase. Following is one such example:

```
struct MnodeInfo {
 uint64_t node;
 int prefix_id;

 MnodeInfo()=default;

 template<class Archive>

 void serialize(Archive & archive)
 {
   archive(node, prefix_id);
 }
};
```

This worked fine until I had to change the `uint64_t` to type `unsigned __int128`(using gcc).
Now I get following error:

> error: static assertion failed: cereal could not find any input
>   serialization functions for the provided type and archive combination.

Is there a workaround for this issue? Can `cereal` be used to (de)serialize non-POD datatypes?

I did consider the using the Boost Multiprecision library (`boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp`) and corresponding serialization support, however was curious if there were alternative approaches that `cereal` offered that could help solve this particular issue.